# How response objects in ResponseEntity are mapped while using RestTemplate?

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, resttemplate

Let's say, I have two microservices MS1 and MS2 and I'm making a call from MS1 to MS2 using RestClient.

Code in MS1:

```
public ResponseEntity<ResponeTypeOne> saveResponse(List<Review> request) {
        String url = getReviewRestServiceEndPoint() + "/ms2/save/";
        return  restTemplate.postForEntity(url, request, ResponeTypeOne.class);
    }
```

Code in MS2: From MS2, I want to send different custom error object (FYI: in case of exception)

```
@ExceptionHandler(MyCustomException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorOutputMessage> handleException(MyCustomException ex){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new ErrorOutputMessage(ex.getCode(),ex.getMessage()),HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
```

Can anyone please tell how the mapping of `ResponeTypeOne` and `ErrorOutputMessage` takes place in following cases:

> 1. When fields in both objects are same.
> 2. When fields in both objects are different.

Answer (score 0):

`RestTemplate` has `DefaultResponseErrorHandler` which throws exception in case of client/server errors (unsuccessful status code).

Comment: I think you didn't get the question @LitalKolog

Comment: I think You did not test the code. I suggest you test it, maybe using MockWebServer(https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver) and you will see that in case of an error(bad request for example) , the client code (MS1) will get an exception with `ErrorOutputMessage` as response body. and in case of success flow your response will be mapped to `ResponeTypeOne` as expected.

Comment: I'm catching exception at MS1. And all I want to know, HOW mapping will take place in case of exception (```ResponseTypeOne```-```ErrorOutputMessage``` mapping). PS: I'm new to all this. @LitalKolog